# JQuery-Javascript: hide() on scrolltop() condition, not taking effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, scrolltop

I have a full-page header with a logo in the center and an arrow below. I need the arrow to disappear if it scrolls up by 10px or more. To this end, I am using `.scrollTop()` and `.hide()` as shown in the following [**jfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/33/). However it does not disappear on scrolling up.

Would appreciate anyone putting me on the right path to find why the arrow isn't hiding with .hide()?

Comment: Jsfiddle doesn't loads jQuery automatically

Comment: but it's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/drake/bg2S4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all include jquery in your jfiddle (settings icon in the js part of the screen). And use the $j also by $j('#arr_down').hide(); and $j('#arr_down').hide(); you forgot the j in your example

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {   
         $j(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($j(this).scrollTop() > 10) 
                 $j('#arr_down').hide();

        else 
                $j('#arr_down').show();
            });
    });
```

Comment: o yes - it works now! thanks for that .